# Obtain text from all items in list using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've written this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://racing4everyone.eu/2016/03/12/formula-e-201516-round05-mexico/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")

options = soup.find_all('option')
```

Now I want to save the text (i.e. 'Placeholder', 'Race') from each element to a variable. I can do it for a single variable:

```
x = soup.find_all('option')[0].text
```

But not for all variables:

```
x = soup.find_all('option')[:].text
```

I know that it is easy to do assuming the list is always the same size, but I want to be able to select all elements in the list regardless of the size. This way, if I apply the code on another webpage it will still work (that webpage's dropdown list might consist of 7 elements for all I know)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `x = soup.find_all('option')[:].text`, you should get the text from each item in the iterator like so:

```
x = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('option')]
```

That way, you get the text attribute from all of the items. If you wish for the most efficient way regarding execution time, you may use this:

```
import operator

x = map(operator.attrgetter("text"), soup.find_all('option'))
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.